# Refresh and show div which existing in other file in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want that whenever my twilio call disconnects, the page should refresh itself automatically and a div that exists in different file should open. Here is my code

```
Twilio.Device.disconnect(function (conn) {
      window.location.reload();
      $('.dhxwin_active').show();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible using querystring URL Like:

```
Twilio.Device.disconnect(function (conn) {
      window.location = window.location.href + "?r=refresh"; // Get the URL Paramerter "r" according your requirement.
      window.location.reload(); 
 });
```

When page refresh you have got "r" value for URL

```
var refresh = '<?php echo $_REQUEST['r'] ;?>';
if(refresh == 'refresh') {
   $('.dhxwin_active').show();
}
```

Please correct me if i am wrong